# how to fill data table in react-data-table-component typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-data-table-component

how to find code data hehe please i need to learn
thank you very much
for your help here

```
import DataTable, { TableColumn } from 'react-data-table-component';


interface DataRow {
    title: string;
    director: string;
    year: string;
}

const columns: TableColumn<DataRow>[] = [
    {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: row => row.title,
    },
    {
        name: 'Director',
        selector: row => row.director,
    },
    {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: row => row.year,
    },
];


function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
    return <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

i hope someone can help me to learn more about this

Comment: could you try to change your selectors  `selector: (row: DataRow)` - the rest looks good.